# Connecting with MySQL Provider

Tags: mysql, ssis

We can write SQL Command from Variable in OLE DB Source Task. How do we get SQL Command from variable in ADO Net Source Task ? Here My Source is MySQL. Because I want to pass a parameter in this SQL Command at WHERE clause. I dont find SQL Command from Variable in ADO.Net Source task. And I cant connect to MySQL in OLE DB Task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression to specify a variable by doing the following:

- On the Control Flow, right click on the Data Flow task and select Properties
- On the Properties window, click the ellipsis for Expressions
- Choose the [ADO NET Source].[SqlCommand] from the Property drop down and click the ellipsis to go to Expression Builder
- In Expression Builder you can reference your variables and add in any SQL clauses you need.

Here is a very rough example...
[image]

Comment: Another doubt is, here the parameter or variable is a date!!! the date format which I am getting and want is "1/12/2008". How will I get the exact format here ?

Comment: Is your variable data type a String holding a date value, or an actual DateTime?